# Stop Gmail opening "Rich formatting" email editor

Tags: gmail

I have configured Gmail to use "Plain Text" when composing emails, this works as it should when I'm *in* Gmail. However when clicking a `mailto` link on a web-page it always opens the "Rich formatting" editor.

Does anyone know how to make it stop doing that?

Comment: Can you add more of a description of what you are trying to achieve. Adding the why as wel would help use find an alternative solution if there is one.

Comment: @MrHinsh - I want it to open the mail composer in `Plain Text` mode, not `Rich formatting`. Now I have to click "Plain Text" then a popup asks me if I really want to do that since I will *loose some formatting*. (Silly question as there is no text at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch to Plain Text composition the choice sticks until you either log out or clear your cookies.